# Graphing Current State in Stepchart

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, graphing

I've been stuck on this for a few days. I have an object that contains:

```
  DateTime Start;
  string State; //current state of Item "ON", "D", "SB", "OFF".
  int Duration; // in seconds
```

I need a step chart that charts the current state of the item by time of day. The chart has time of day along the bottom. States on Y axis 1 and duration on y axis 2. I know the data is getting through, because I have a table below the chart that displays the same data.

I currently have start on `Category` fields and `Duration` on secondary axis and `Status` on regular axis.  The main problem is it's not graphing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out I had to set a switch to get the state to graph correctly on the positions. I then hid the labels and put the correct tags in place. Also when I set the date time for the x axis and set it to increment by hours it set the current day I made that change so when I handed it a day in the past it threw the whole set out as not meeting the criteria.